# How to find the intersection of n arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

`[1, 2, 3] & [2, 3, 4]` gives us `[2, 3]` but how do you get the intersection of n arrays?

`[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4]].something` would give `[3]`

Looping with `&` works but there must be a better way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4]].inject(:&) #=> [3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just & all arrays. Suppose you have 3 arrays.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4]
c = [3,4,5]

a & b & c
=> [3]
```